# SHBrowseForFolder - how to let the window always on the top?

Tags: c++, windows

In my codes which i call the SHBrowseForFloder function and now i want to let the dialog always on the top.But i can not find the parameter which can do that. Some one can help me ?Or whether should i choose the other API to reailze this feature?

Comment: the windows on the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want SHBrowseForFolder to be on top of its parent window then you must set the parent in your BROWSEINFO structure.

```
BROWSEINFO bi;

bi.hwndOwner = <handle to the parent window>;
```

Comment: i am using visual studio .And it is "application program". So there is no parent window, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by application program. Are you creating a console app? Because application program would have a application window. May be if you can share some code here in your question that I may be able to help. You want the user to browse for folder. But normally there would be an underlying window from where the user triggers browsing for folder.

Comment: The SHBrowserForFolder API have a callback function.And in the callback API which have the parameters that name "HWND hwnd".So i need not get the window handle by myself.And the i used the API SetWindowPos to set the window TOPmost.